# RSS Google news language

Tags: rss, google-news

I am creating a RSS feed from Google News and it's working so far, but I'd like to get news from 2 languages, not just English

This is my RSS URL so far:

https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=energy+efficiency

It's working fine, just need to add the 2 languages filter (German + English)

This is what I've found in different blogs, but I do not wish to filter the news by location, just by language:

"If you wish to have news in English and located from the United States sources, add the following query string to the URL to change country and language:"

&hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US:en

No matter how I modify the above URL, I get an error...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading lots of posts and playing around, I found the solution.

In case someone needs it:
https://news.google.com/rss?q=energy+efficiency&hl=en

Add the language code at the end of the link:

&hl=en   //English

&hl=de   //German

Comment: What does "hl" stand for?

Comment: "hl" stands for "host language."  This is the language that your end user is assumed to be typing in.  For instance, typing "study" when trying to find "studie" would imply that the host language is English.